# How do I match the first character right after a substitution in the regex?

Tags: regex

#### Updated Problem

I want to replace all '\n's with '\r\n' except for those that are 
'\r\n' already, so I came up with this:
`'\n\n\r\n1\n'.replace(/((\r\n)+|^|[^\r])\n((?!\r)|(?=\r\n))/g, '$1\r\n')`

But it produces:
`'\r\n\n\r\n1\r\n'`

If I use `'\n\n\r\n1\n'.replace(/((\r\n)+|^|[^\r]|)\n((?!\r)|(?=\r\n))/g, '$1\r\n')`, it ignores all prerequsites and produces: `"\r\n\r\n\r\r\n1\r\n"`.

How can I achieve it? Thanks a lot.

BTW, it's tested in the Chrome 68.

---

#### Original Problem (for context):

<s>I thought that the replaced characters would be counted as a part of the string when regex engine continues to test. So I got this one.</s>

`'1111'.replace(/(^|[^2])1/g, '$12')
"2121"`

But now I'm confused by the following statement, I expected '2222' instead.

`'1111'.replace(/(^|[^3])1/g, '$12')
"2121"`

It seems the character after the replaced one is ignored somehow. I can't capture it even with '.'.

`'1111'.replace(/(^|.)1/g, '$12')
"2121"`

How can I replace every '1' in the example?

I know that `'1111'.replace(/1/g ,2)` does, but it's a simplified example, I want to replace the target by some prerequisites like what's demonstrated above.

BTW, it's tested in the Chrome 68.

Comment: Please give us the real problem, not a simplified unclear version of it.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Well, a lookbehind will work here, `(?<!2)1`

Comment: Why the simple version is not valid? What are your prerrequisites?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your time, I updated the question with a real problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately, lookbehind is not supported as of Chrome 68 or node 8.9.4 without --harmony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `((\r\n)+|^|[^\r])\n((?!\r)|(?=\r\n))` pattern matches:

- `((\r\n)+|^|[^\r])` - Group 1: one or more CRLF sequences (`(\r\n)+`) or (`|`) the start of a string (`|`) or any char but a CR (`[^\r]`)
- `\n` - a newline, LF
- `((?!\r)|(?=\r\n))` - not followed with CR or followed with CRLF.

So, when applied to `\n\n\r\n1\n` the following happens:

- At the start of the string, `^` is captured into Group 1, `\n` is matched and `(?!\r)` returns true, hence, there is a match (the first `\n` is matched). It is replaced with `\r\n` as `$1` is empty string. The result is `\r\n` currently.
- The next match is searched for from the second `\n` (`\n\r\n1\n` remains to be consumed). `\n` is captured into Group 1 with `[^\r]`, `\r` does not match `\n` => fail. `\n` is put back, the regex index is advanced to the next position. Here, we have `\r\n\n` in the result.
- `\r\n1\n` remains to be consumed. `\r` does not match, hence added to the result as is, `\r\n\n\r`. The `\n1\n` remains to be consumed.
- `\n` is captured into Group 1 with `[^\r]`, `1` cannot be matched with `\n`, no match is found, `\n` is appended to the result, `\r\n\n\r\n`.
- `1\n` remains to be consumed. `1` is matched with `[^\r]`, `\n` is matched with `\n` and `(?!\r)` returns true => there is a match, so this `1\n` is replaced with `1\r\n` (as `$1` contains `1`).

You may match the `\r\n` sequences and then `\n` chars in other contexts and replace both with `\r\n`:

```js
console.log(
    JSON.stringify('\n\n\r\n1\n'.replace(/\r\n|\n/g, '\r\n'))
);
```

This way, the CLRF and LF endings are normalized to CRLF.

**Details**

- `\r\n` - a CRLF ending
- `|` - or
- `\n` - an LF ending.

Comment: Thanks. It's a more decent solution, I'm still curious about the reason why some characters can't be captured by capture group way in this case. Do you happen to know about it?

Comment: @pansila Which regex do you want to understand, `((\r\n)+|^|[^\r])\n((?!\r)|(?=\r\n))` or `(^|.)1/g`?

Comment: @pansila I added the explanation at the top.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to capture the following `\n` after the first replacement? I thought that `(^|[^\r])` would do that.

Comment: @pansila Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I updated the summary of the question, I mean how I can match the first character right after the position where a previous substitution happens. Namely, how can I refine the regex in the question to make it produce `'\r\n\r\n\r\n1\r\n'` instead of `'\r\n\n\r\n1\r\n'`?

Comment: @pansila I already posted the answer, `.replace(/\r\n|\n/g, '\r\n')`. Your approach CAN'T work, and I explained why. A lookbehind is necessary if supported, `(?<!\r)\n`.